# compostion of p-adic power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

This question arises from *$p$-adic Numbers: an Introduction* written by Gouvea. It is problem 148 in the book.

Let $f(x)=1+x+x^2/2!+\cdots+ x^n/n!+\cdots$ be the exponential series as a formal power series and $g(x)=2x^2-2x$. Let $h(x)=f(g(x))=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_nx^n$ be their formal compostion (not necessarily the compostion as functions), which has rational coefficients.

How to prove that ${\rm ord}_2(a_n)\ge 1+ n/4$ when $n\ge 2$? (Here ${\rm ord}_2$ is the 2-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}_2$.)

This is an important part of the construction of a  counterexample that says that the value of a formal compostion series $f(g(x))$ where it converges sometimes may not agree with the compostion of the individual series $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ where they converge.

The first few terms of $h(x)$ look like this:
$h(x)=1-2x+4x^2-\frac{16}{3}x^3+\frac{20}{3}x^4-\frac{104}{15}x^5+\frac{304}{45}x^6\dots$

The author thinks this question is rather hard and he recommends  *Cyclotomic Field I and II* by Lang (Chapter 14, Section 2) to look for a hint about why this particular power series is interesting.

I have already written down the formula $a_n$.
$$a_n=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{2^{n-k}}{k!(n-2k)!}$$

Comment: @reuns $b_8=\frac{2^8}{8!}$ and $v_2(b_8)=1<1+4$. I don't know the meaning of this inequality.

Comment: Since this is a question about $2$-adic behavior, I wouldn't bring up their ordinary "absolute value" at the end of the answer.  Just allow a $\pm$ outside the sum if you don't want to pin it down more precisely.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have edited my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gouvea says the problem is hard because it *is* hard. It is the type of problem where the solution uses something far beyond what it takes to understand the statement of the problem alone. It is not reasonable to expect a full solution to be written here for you.

Here is something that at first does not look relevant. For two $p$-adic formal power series $A(x) = \sum a_nx^n$ and $B(x) = \sum b_nx^n$, set $C(x) = A(x)B(x) = \sum c_nx^n$ as a product of formal power series, so
$c_n = \sum_{j=0}^n a_jb_{n-j}$ for all $n \geq 0$. Letting $v = {\rm ord}_p$, show that if $v(a_n) \geq Kn+L$ and $v(b_n) \geq Kn + L$ for all $n$, where $K > 0$ and $L \geq 0$ then $v(c_n) \geq Kn+L$ for all $n$ too. Thus the space of $p$-adic power series $\sum a_nx^n$ whose coefficients tend to $0$ in absolute value at least as quickly as a “common geometric series” (meaning $|a_n|_p \leq (1/p)^{Kn+L} = (1/p)^L(1/p^K)^n$) is closed under multiplication.

The application of this idea to your example needs something *not* in the book, which is partly why Gouvea calls it a hard problem: the $2$-adic Artin-Hasse series
$$
{\rm AH}_2(x) = e^{x + x^2/2+x^4/4+x^8/8+\cdots},
$$
which despite the way it looks actually has coefficients in $\mathbf Z_2$, so the $2$-adic valuations of its coefficients are all nonnegative, unlike the coefficients of $e^x$ or even $e^{2x}$. (I am not saying the coefficients of this series tend to $0$ in the $2$-adics: they don’t, as infinitely many coefficients will be $2$-adic units, which is not obvious and also irrelevant.)

The series you call $h(x)$ is $e^{2x^2-2x}$. Let $E(x) = e^{x+x^2/2}$, so $h(x) = E(-2x)$. Note the roots of $x+x^2/2$ are $0$ and $-2$, so you would naively think $E(-2)$ is $e^0 = 1$, but it is $-1$, and likewise $h(1)$ is not $1$ but instead $-1$. To prove $E(x)$ converges at $-2$ or $h(x)$ converges at $1$, write
$$
E(x) = {\rm AH}_2(x)\prod_{k\geq 2} e^{-x^{2^k}/2^k},
$$
so replacing $x$ with $-2x$ turns this into
$$
h(x) = {\rm AH}_2(-2x)\prod_{k\geq 2}e^{-2^{2^k-k}x^{2^k}}.
$$
and use the result I mentioned at the start on all the series that are factors on the right side of this equation. To get a sense of why the right side is very good for you, the first series ${\rm AH}_2(-2x)$ converges at $1$ since its coefficients tend to $0$ in $\mathbf Q_2$ at least like $2^n$, and the factor at $k=2$ in the product is $e^{-4x^4}$, which also converges at $1$ since the coefficients of $e^{4x}$ tend to $0$ in $\mathbf Q_2$. The rate of convergence at $1$ only gets better with the factors at larger $k$.

That approach to the problem is hard, as Gouvea writes about the problem overall, but it does lead to success, in contrast to writing
$$
h(x) = e^{-2x+2x^2} = e^{-2x}e^{2x^2}
$$
since neither of the two factors on the right converges at $1$ in $\mathbf Q_2$.

Follow Gouvea’s advice to look at Lang’s book. Or you could look in Section $2$ of Chapter $7$ of Robert’s *A Course in $p$-adic Analysis* (especially the theorem on p. $396$) or [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/AHrootofunity.pdf) (especially Corollary $3.9$).

Comment: But in my question, the operator between formal power series is compostion.

Comment: Just because the operator *looks* like composition doesn’t mean you must view it only in that way for this problem. Otherwise you will not solve the problem. I have updated my answer with some more details.

Comment: Thank you. It is interesting that I can explicitly write down the formula of $a_n$ and it will look like an elementary number theory problem. However, the tool to solve this problem is far from elementary approach.

Comment: I think a simpler example of the phenomena you bring up is the numbers $s_n = 2 + 2^2/2 + \cdots + 2^n/n$, which are the partial sums of $-\log(1-x) = \sum x^n/n$ at $x = 2$: they converge $2$-adically to $\log(-1) = 0$ (note $2$ is in the $2$-adic disc of convergence of $-\log(1-x)$), so ${\rm ord}_2(s_n) \to \infty$ but this is not obvious from the definition of $s_n$, whose $2$-adic behavior looks a bit erratic: the first $10$ values of ${\rm ord}_2(s_n)$ are 1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 5, 5, 13, 9, 10, so they don't grow monotonically.